# How can Lucene's scoring depend on relative position of query?

Tags: java, search, lucene

I use `WhitespaceAnalyzer` as query analyzer.
If I have 2 documents:

```
| text | a b c |
| text | b a c |
```

`text` is a field.

Now the index structure is something like this:

```
|Term|  in document | 
| a  | a b c / b a c|
| b  | a b c / b a c|
| c  | a b c / b a c|
```

And I have a query:

```
| text | a b c |
```

How can I get a higher score for `a b c` and a lower one for `b a c`.

Does Lucene support calculating score depending on **relative position**?

I found that I found this would help:

```
PhraseQuery phraseQuery = new PhraseQuery();
phraseQuery.setSlop(1);
```

In this way they would get different scores.

See more: http://www.blogjava.net/tangzurui/archive/2008/09/22/230357.html

`And here I come across another question:` 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394532/how-can-lucenes-scoring-depend-on-terms-relative-position-in-the-document

Answer (score 0):

It depends on, which type of query you use. Some query could get more score, if phrase that you search is placed in correct order (e.g. new york or york new). According to Lucene documentation, you could use explanation of score, to see, why A B C is geting higher score than B A C.

> Scoring is very much dependent on the way documents are indexed, so it
>   is important to understand indexing (see Apache Lucene - Getting
>   Started Guide and the Lucene file formats before continuing on with
>   this section.) It is also assumed that readers know how to use the
>   Searcher.explain(Query query, int doc) functionality, which can go a
>   long way in informing why a score is returned.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/scoring.html

UPD. For storing position of terms look at this, if you using Lucene 3
http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.TermVector.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm afraid that I didn't make it clear. I mean in the case I said before the score is the same for both case. I just wonder how to make the final score depending on relative position. After the Analyzer processed the input, infect we get the same structure in index for both case.

Comment: So, you need to take a look at analyzer that store position. I will update the answer

Comment: I think that termVector is mainly for highlighting. I found a better solution as I said above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The score contribution of a phrase match depends on the distance:

- highest score for distance=0 (exact match).
- score gets lower as distance gets higher.

For your case query "a b c" will match with document "a b c" with distance 0. This will result to highest phrase score. For document "b a c" distance will be more than 0. So Score will be less.

For more details look at source code of **org.apache.lucene.search.SloppyPhraseScorer** Class.

Comment: I found this would help:  PhraseQuery phraseQuery = new PhraseQuery();
        phraseQuery.setSlop(3);